# Box plot a data from dictionaries key in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, boxplot

I have two dictionaries, both dictionaries contains a number of keys. What i am trying to do here. I want to plot their data side by side.  For example both dictionaries have key '1', so i want to plot the data of key 1 from both dictionaries side by side.

```
dict_a = {1: [10.60626299560636,9.808507783184758, 9.80184985166152, 9.820483229791137,9.822087257017674],
2: [10.60626299560636, 9.808507783184758, 9.80184985166152, 9.820483229791137, 9.822087257017674]}  

dict_b = {1: [14.420548834522766,13.886147271592971,14.522980401561725,14.876615652026173,13.379224382776899],
2: [14.650926514851816,13.984378530820885,14.566825972585173, 16.434690726796628,15.24108978696146]}
```

after a search i came to towards the following code, but both code snippets helps to draw for one dict at one time.

```
 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 ax.boxplot(dict_a .values())
 ax.set_xticklabels(dict_a.keys())
```

Another code which i found is following but still it does not give me what i want.

```
 labels, data = dict_a .keys(), dict_a .values()

 plt.boxplot(data)
 plt.xticks(range(1, len(labels) + 1), labels)
 plt.show()
```

is there a way, which performs the same way i want.

Comment: If you want to compare a[1] with b[1] what should happen with a[2] and b[2]? Nothing? Is the end result 2 boxplots or 4? Or do you mean 1 box for key 1 of a *and* b and another box for key 2 of a and b?

Comment: basically, it should be 4 box plot in total. But first a[1] next  to b[1] , then a[2] next to b[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
key = 1
values = [data[key] for data in [dict_a, dict_b]]  
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(values)
ax.set_xticklabels(['dict_a', 'dict_b'])
ax.set_title('value: %s' % key)
```

[image: Resulting Figure]